# Is it safe to put private API keys in your .m files when exporting to the appstore?

Tags: ios, xcode, encryption, export, ipa

I have an app that uses some APIs that allow me to do tasks that cost me money (1 cent per request etc). These APIs have private keys and I'm obviously not supposed to share the keys with anyone.

How exactly are iphone apps encrypted? If I include these keys in my .m files in my app and then export to IPA and send to the AppStore are they safe or can someone potentially crack my IPA open and get my keys that are hardcoded in.

I know I shouldn't put these in my info.plist or anything because those are visible to anyone who has access to the IPA files. But is it safe to put API secrets and API keys in my .m files before exporting to the AppStore?

Edit: My API keys are being sent to the API servers across an **HTTPS** request, not http

Comment: Yes if it is in a .m file a user could get your key.  If your app makes any request with the key at all somebody could get it easily by sending their network traffic through a proxy anyway even if they couldn't pull it from the binary.

Comment: @dan True! And I do use http requests. Hmmm, I suppose I could have it send the trigger to AWS and have the API calls be made server side.

Comment: @dan Can you tell us how given that the executable files are encrypted by Apple? If the connection is https with the server running TLS 1.2 and Perfect Forward Secrecy and the server certificate is pinned there can be no MITM or proxy that has access to the data un-encrypted.

Comment: @zaph I'm curious about this too, I am using HTTPS

Comment: @zaph There's multiple tools that exist to decrypt your executable and then a simple `strings` command will get you any API keys you have hardcoded in your app.  Users with jailbroken devices can debug your app and pull the keys straight from memory before anything is encrypted for SSL.  They can also patch your app themselves to disable certificate pinning and then view your SSL requests in mitmproxy or a similar tool.

Comment: @dan There are is no tool to decrypt the executable other than the OS. It seems that you are proposing that there is no solution but one is needed. But the thing about security is the work factor, that is the level of difficulty to obtain the key, the point is to increase it. Pinning the certificate increases the work factor. Requiring jailbreaking and live debugging increases the work factor. None of these attacks are based on the API key being hard-coded in the app. If the app has a login function then the API key can be obtained then and not be built into the app.

Comment: @zaph There is absolutely tools to decrypt the executable.  I've personally used https://github.com/KJCracks/Clutch and there are others like it.  I was just answering the question that users can get your API key if you hardcode it in your app.  I think the chance of anyone bothering to do that is extemely low unless its like an AWS key or something.  I send down the API keys on login in all my apps and I'm not really worried about someone going through to effort to get the key.

Comment: If you are really worried about your keys being stolen I would keep them on your server and have the app make requests to your own server where you have better control over detecting suspicious activity.

Comment: @dan I just want to make sure before I do this because my app has about 1,000,000+ downloads and the API requests cost me $0.01 per request already with just the APIs. If I'm ALSO sending a request to Parse or something and then from there running the API requests it could double my overhead haha.

Comment: Clutch requires a jailbroken iPhone and requires a substantial amount of knowledge to use thus it has a somewhat high work factor, it is not as simple as using iExplorer. It does not work by decrypting the app but by running the app and capturing the decrypted binary just after iOS loads it to execute but before execution, iOS does the actual decryption. Removing certificate pinning adds substantially more work factor and technical competence.

Comment: Embedding API keys in an app is not secure and generally not a good practice but does require a substantial work factor to obtain them, it is not trivial. But it may meet the security needs. You need to determine who the attacker is, how much skill and time the attacker will spend and the cost to you. There is no 100% secure solution. To have the app make requests to your own server moves the problem to authentication the request to your server, that probably will be no easier to secure.