# Why is it safe to put secret keys into iOS binaries

Tags: ios

I've noticed several tutorials for most of the major players in social networks have examples where a API key tied to your account is embedded (usually in plan text) in the source code.  For example, [Google Maps APIs Premium Plan](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/ios-get-started#get_an_api_key_from_the_console_name).  This key is used to bill your company.

I found a similar question in [Is it safe to put private API keys in your .m files when exporting to the appstore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496050/is-it-safe-to-put-private-api-keys-in-your-m-files-when-exporting-to-the-appsto])[1](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/ios-get-started#get_an_api_key_from_the_console_name) - Of note, **anyone with a jailbroken phone can see the unencrypted executable**.

Is this practice actually safe, and if so, why?

Comment: What more are you looking for that isn't covered in the comments to the question you linked? It isn't safe to put plain text keys in your code, just as the comments state.

Comment: Ideally you should not have any hardcoded keys. If you have, you need to obfuscate them.

Comment: @Krypton Obfuscation is secure? Please explain.

Comment: @rmaddy It isn't safe to ever have the keys in memory at any time, they can be recovered at execution time. So, there is always a vulnerability, it is all about increasing the work factor the attacker will have to overcome to meet the security goals.

Comment: There are two types of security: 1) by design 2) by obfuscation
- Security by design is effective even against determined hackers
- Security by obfuscation does not guarantee security. However it does slow down determined professional hackers and deter the amateurs. You embedded your key in your app, so definitely this is a bad design. So you may want to obfuscate your app well enough.

Comment: @Krypton No. The difference is that cryptographic security does not rely on the method being secret, only that the key is secret. Obfuscation relies on the method being secret. It has been shown that relying on the method being secret does not produce security. On an iPhone the binary code is not available for inspection until it is loaded for execution in RAM. It is not until that point that an attacker can access the binary code to find the key and also at that point it is also possible to access the key when it is used, that is when it is added to the network request.

Comment: @Krypton All security is simply raising the work factor of an attack. This applies to the biggest bank vault doors (which are mainly for show) to the best crypto. The attack may be trivial to very complicated. Lacking extreme physical security any time a key is in memory it is vulnerable. That is why at the high end HSMs [(Hardware Security Modules)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module) are used, where the key is never in computer memory, never available to the computer. We can't accomplish this on an iPhone but Apple has with the Secure Enclave.

Comment: not necessarily, there have been a couple of white box crypto libraries that hardcode keys within the code. If the keys are obfuscated well enough even in the memory, it could be good enough to deter attackers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedding API keys in an app is not secure and generally not a good practice but does require a substantial work factor to obtain them, it is not trivial. There is no tool to decrypt the executable other than the OS for execution.

RE: "anyone with a jailbroken phone can see the unencrypted executable." is not really true. Just jailbreaking will not decrypt the app binary, it is only decrypted as the binary is loaded in RAM to execute and the key will not be available, it is decrypted in hardware in the DMA path. One needs to add debugging tools and catch the binary after it is loaded into memory for execution.

You need to determine who the attacker is, how much skill and time the attacker will spend and the cost to you.

There is no 100% secure solution, only increasing the work factor.
An alternative is to obtain the API keys on first run at login to a server and then move them to the Keychain. But this is also just an increase in work factor because as above the executable can be examined at run time when it is sent to the service.

As long as the key has to be in the app memory during any part of execution it is vulnerable.

Putting the API keys in the source may meet the security needs.